# How do I add watermark for photos already in Picasa web?

Tags: metadata, flickr, picasa, watermark, 500px

Is it possible to add visible/invisible watermark to photos *already uploaded* to Picasa Web/500px/Flickr?

Do they preserve EXIF(metadata) of the image?

I am looking for free tools/services. If downloading software is required, I would prefer Linux/Ubuntu.

Update:
In the light of two answers already given; adding a clarification. A solution that lets adding the watermark *without downloading the photos from the respective locations* is asked for.

Comment: Downvoting without comment isn't helpful just rude

Comment: @ClaraOnager Sorry I don't get you. I can't even upvote!!

Comment: Not you, someone else downvoted for no apparent reason

Comment: What are you trying to do here? I have to admit, I can see why it was down voted as the question, given the way it was worded, would imply a less-than-savoury need here.

Comment: JoanneC: Sorry, may I know what is wrong in the question? Does it sound something else? If so, please help in re-phrasing it.

Comment: It kind of sounds like you're trying to watermark other people's images. Otherwise, why would you need to? You still have your original images do you not?

Comment: Oh no; I don't want to re-upload all of them to their respective albums. And by the way one cannot access some other's account to alter their images; without their consent.

Comment: You can download other's images and do it though. Anyways, I see what your asking then, which is kind of what I figured, but others may not have and so that was my speculation on the down vote.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok. I am not sure what you are asking, but I can try to guess.

If a photo is already uploaded, it is rather difficult to modify, as that copy is no longer on your computer.

I suggest downloading the photo, applying the watermark in photoshop/gimp (A free, open source version of photoshop), and re-uploading. I am not sure if this will preserve the metadata though.

As to how to apply a watermark in gimp, that is another question entirely.

Comment: @Stephan Thanks, I am looking for a solution that might let me do it without downloading them.

Comment: I am accepting your answer, as there may not be a better answer than this one.

Answer (score 2):

I will provide all who visit this page with a working answer, having in mind that this is now 2015:

Of course you can have you images uploaded to a Google+ album and still have you originals on your computer. Supposing you have uploaded the images with Picasa 3 and you still have the connection in Picasa with both the local and online album.

What you need to do to ad a watermark, change a watermark or remove a watermark from any already uploaded images is to have Picasa overwrite the online images with a fresh copy. One way of doing that on a PC is:

Set up Picasa to ad whatever watermark you want or have to set no watermark at all.

Select all images in the local album, Press Ctrl + R (turn all of them 90 deg right), let Picasa sync everthing in the album, then press Ctrl+Shift+R (turn them back again), and then let Picasa sync everthing again.

All images in the online album will now be updated with any new watermark settings you applied before the procedure.